# My app crashes when scrolling a pop-up

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I'm developing an android app that requires me to get some images from a server in order to display it in a scrollable pop-up once that pop-up is requested by the user, i'm trying to get all the images using [universalImageLoader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) and storing them as a `Bitmaps` but when getting the images and also after i got all of it, i got infinite displaying of `GC_FOR_ALLOC` lines, and when pressing the button that displays the pop_up, the pop_up displayed normally but when begin to scroll down my app crashes and i got the following log messages:

```
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 03-09 08:57:40.758   107:  107 I/DEBUG    ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Build fingerprint: 'generic/vbox86tp/vbox86tp:4.3/JLS36G/eng.buildbot.20140128.092034:userdebug/test-keys'
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 03-09 08:57:40.758   107:  107 I/DEBUG    ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Revision: '0'
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 03-09 08:57:40.758   107:  107 I/DEBUG    ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): pid: 2269, tid: 2269, name: xample.solaceap  >>> com.example.solaceap <<<
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 03-09 08:57:40.758   107:  107 I/DEBUG    ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2 (SEGV_ACCERR), fault addr 97808030
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 03-09 08:57:40.898   107:  107 I/DEBUG    ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     eax 00000000  ebx b757b6ff  ecx 0000000a  edx 9780803a
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 03-09 08:57:40.898   107:  107 I/DEBUG    ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     esi 00000008  edi 00000001
.
.
.
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): channel '5284e038 com.example.solaceap/com.example.solaceap.Login (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 03-09 08:57:41.014   479:  518 E/InputDispatcher ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): channel '5284e038 com.example.solaceap/com.example.solaceap.Login (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): [ 03-09 08:57:41.022   479:  518 W/InputDispatcher ]
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): channel '528b7508 PopupWindow:52a6ec40 (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Grow heap (frag case) to 6.773MB for 196620-byte allocation
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 7K, 27% free 6864K/9292K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '5287e6f8 com.example.solaceap/com.example.solaceap.MainPage (server)'
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Process com.example.solaceap (pid 2269) has died.
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): WIN DEATH: Window{528afe84 u0 com.example.solaceap/com.example.solaceap.Media}
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '528afe84 com.example.solaceap/com.example.solaceap.Media (server)'
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Force-removing child win Window{528b7508 u0 PopupWindow:52a6ec40} from container Window{528afe84 u0 com.example.solaceap/com.example.solaceap.Media}
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Failed looking up window
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested window android.os.BinderProxy@5281f9fc does not exist
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:7630)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:7621)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at com.android.server.wm.WindowState$DeathRecipient.binderDied(WindowState.java:1000)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at android.os.BinderProxy.sendDeathNotice(Binder.java:470)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at com.android.server.SystemServer.init1(Native Method)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:1066)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): WIN DEATH: null
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Late-enabling CheckJNI
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Start proc com.example.solaceap for activity com.example.solaceap/.MainPage: pid=2310 uid=10050 gids={50050, 3003, 1015, 1028}
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 39K, 4% free 2502K/2604K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/<unknown>(<unknown>): Grow heap (frag case) to 5.000MB for 2621452-byte allocation
```

And this is how i get the images:

```
ImageLoader loader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
public static Map<Integer, Bitmap> movies_bitmaps = new HashMap<Integer, Bitmap>();

loader.loadImage(url, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view,
                            Bitmap loadedImage) {
                        try {
                            int size = loadedImage.getWidth()
                                    * loadedImage.getHeight();
                            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(
                                    size);
                            Bitmap modified_image = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(loadedImage, 180, 230, false);
                            modified_image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100,
                                    stream);
                            movies_bitmaps.put(index, modified_image);
                            loadedImage.recycle();
                            stream.close();
                            modified_image = null;
                            stream = null;
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

Comment: This is dangerous, `} catch (Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();`.  Have you actually checked whether you are getting an exception?

Comment: @Simon why is a try/catch block dangerous? As for your issue, the crash is explained very well: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested window android.os.BinderProxy@5281f9fc does not exist`

Comment: I didn't say try-catch is dangerous, of course it's not, but catching and doing nothing, especially when catching `Exception`, is because it effectively ignores any IO exceptions.  What happens to `stream` after this snippet has executed?

Comment: Your code is going about doing nothing... first you create a `ByteArrayOutputStream` with the size equal to image width*height, which is wrong no matter how you look at it: if you were writing raw bitmap data it should be 4*width*height, but you are writing a compressed JPG, whose resultant size would not correlate with image width/height. Then you close and set the stream to null so nothing is accomplished. Then you call `loadedImage.recycle()` so **loadedImage cannot ever be used again**, but you put it in a Map with a clear intent to use it later...

Comment: Try removing `loadedImage.recycle()` and see if it helps, and read Android doc on `Bitmap.recycle()`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#recycle()

Comment: @Kai apparently removing `loadedImage.recycle()` solved my problem, but i didn't get it, the images are displayed efficiently before that even when using `loadedImage.recycle()` , so if that clearing the Bitmap, why the images were there then? and why the class took a lot of MegaBytes of my memory then? also the `GC_FOR_ALLOC` messages still there.

Comment: @MRefaat I am moving my comment as an answer since it solved your question, for your other questions see the answer as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is going about doing nothing... first you create a `ByteArrayOutputStream` with the size equal to image width*height, which is wrong no matter how you look at it: if you were writing raw bitmap data it should be 4*width*height, but you are writing a compressed JPG, whose resultant size would not correlate with image width/height. Then you close and set the stream to null so nothing is accomplished. Then you call `loadedImage.recycle()` so loadedImage cannot ever be used again, but you put it in a Map with a clear intent to use it later...

Try removing loadedImage.recycle() and see if it helps, and read Android doc on [Bitmap.recycle()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#recycle%28%29):

---

To answer some of your other questions in the comments:

> so if that clearing the Bitmap, why the images were there then?

Per Android documenation:

> This will not free the pixel data synchronously; it simply allows it
>   to be garbage collected if there are no other references.

Basically it means if you called `recycle()`, subsequent behavior is undefined as far API is concerned. If memory serves, the behavior is different pre-Andorid 4.0 and post(including) Android 4.0, since they've moved the byte[] buffer backing a Bitmap from native memory space into VM managed memory space.

---

> GC_FOR_ALLOC messages still there.

Because you are still creating lots of large objects, it's normal. If you want to reduce it, remove the `ByteArrayOutputStream` and associated code.